# replacing accordion placeholder with more content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently building a website based around the idea of being a one page site.  I currently have a main view like

```
<div id="right-content">
<div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
```

Within another view I have some ajax that populates the `#accordion` with the returned data, the returned is placed in its only uniquely id'd `div`.  How do I get this data to act as an accordion?  I have tried the script in both the right-content view and the main view and get no accordion functionality. In essence what I currently have when some data has been fetched is this

```
<div id="right-content">
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="blog">
            <h2>Blog Header</<h2><!--This should be the click area for the accordion-->
            <p>Content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content
            content content content contentcontentcontent content content content</p>
           <!--<p> should be hidden unless this accordion is active</p>
    </div>
```

I think my issue may be that each 'accordion' is being placed in its own div first, this is not how it is on the [accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) example.

Please can someone help me figure this out? 
Many thanks

Comment: i think you need to call `$("#accordion").accordion();` everytime after you load the ajax. you can't rely on the one call done in `$(document).ready()` to work on new elements added to the page after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple markup errors in your HTML sample. Several closing tags for `<div>` are missing.

The closing tag for your `h2` is wrong `</<h2>` instead of `</h2>`

So I guess you really mean your markup to look like this

```
<div id="right-content">
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="blog">
            <!-- Note the additional <a> tag to get the accordion arrows -->
            <h2><a>Blog Header</a></h2>
            <p>Content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog2">
            <h2><a>Blog Header 2</a></h2>
            <p>Content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now all you need to do is to specify the correct `header` option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run your ajax stuff
    // when you are done inserting all the stuff
    // run this (after ajax operations are completed)
    $('#accordion').accordion({header:'h2'});
});
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/ubiwa for a working example